# how to run swagger editor generated springmvc server from intellij?

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea, swagger

I have created a YAML file using swagger-editor and downloaded springMVC generated server from the editor.

I have opened the project on Intellij IDE and did mvn clean & compile.

I have run: mvn clean & compile, and jetty run
but i can not see a working rest api on http://localhost:8002

what am i missing? am i running the generated springmvc wrong?

Comment: i have tried the example on: http://editor.swagger.io/#/

Answer (score 1):

There should be a readme.md in the generated artifacts that have instructions on going to  `http://localhost:8002/v2/swagger-ui.html`  To verify everything is in order.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the swagger definition the context path and port might be generated differently. Check the generated application.properties file for the below keys

```
server.contextPath=/api
server.port=8090
```